# how to rename folder in codeigniter rename folder is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

In my project i have language folder. if new language created a new folder will generate. And if we want to rename language, its folder should be rename.

```
$res =  $this->db->get_where('languages',array('l_id'=>$data['id']))- 
>result_array();    
rename(APPPATH.'/language/'.$result[0]['l_eng'], $data['l_eng']);
```

Comment: use `FCPATH` instead of `APPPATH` and  use `FCPATH` for both old and new path

Comment: I just checked FCPATH But not working

Comment: make sure ,it should be `$res[0]['l_eng']` not `$result[0]['l_eng']`